# Can I get record by object id rather than index

Tags: octobercms

I have an array of objects coming into my page and can display them using the index of the record in the array.
Example:

```
{{ records[0].image}}
```

`{{ records}}` looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"image one",
        "created_at":"2019-09-10 11:46:46",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-10 12:00:17",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "desc":"lady being driven",
        "image":"\/cropped-images\/chauffer1-86-2-708-593-1568116001.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "name":"image 2",
        "created_at":"2019-09-10 11:47:38",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-10 12:01:02",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "desc":"driver",
        "image":"\/cropped-images\/chauffer2-5-3-817-764-1568116053.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "name":"background",
        "created_at":"2019-09-10 12:17:02",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-10 12:17:02",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "desc":"background image of a city from above at night",
        "image":"\/nightcity.jpg"
    }
]
```

How do I get the record by the 'id' or any key?

Answer (score 0):

from php side I guess your records are in $records array, so we need to rearrange them

```
$relativeRecords = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $relativeRecords[$record['id']] = $record;
    // $relativeRecords[$record->id] = $record; // use this if your source is object.
}
```

> `$relativeRecords` will look like this now

```
[
    [3] => {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"image one",
        "created_at":"2019-09-10 11:46:46",
        "updated_at":"2019-09-10 12:00:17",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "desc":"lady being driven",
        "image":"\/cropped-images\/chauffer1-86-2-708-593-1568116001.jpg"
    }

    ....
```

> and now you can access them like `{{ records[3].image }}`

if any doubts please comment

Comment: Not allowed to answer my own question :(
Thanks Hardik, I totally see where you are coming from.
OctoberCMS uses a weird markup I'm not experienced with.

At the top of an OctoberCMS .htm page I have the component input like this

    {% set records = builderList.records %}

And to get the record by a key I had to do this

    {% for record in records %}
       {% if record.id == '3' %}
           {{ record.image }}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: Hmm yes if its coming from ` {% set records = builderList.records %}` builder then you can not edit it, but if in future if you made component and you pass variables to view you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a follow up answer to provide more of an explanation. Lets say model records are objects and are retrieved using as an eloquent collection. With Twig markup (not a weird markup but a good one) you are working with array like objects. In the backend you are working with collections (which are super powered arrays).

So I like calling the data inside a record its properties and values and not key and value. I do this because every array has a key value. This array `[ [ 'id' => 1, 'name'=> 'something' ] ]` I can access this array with Twig either by a foreach loop `{% for item in array %}` or by key index of `{{ array[0] }}`. Now I can specify with dot notation or key notation `[]` the property I want to select. Simple so far with Twig.

Now how do I make a criteria and choose a specific record in a collection. Well the Twig foreach loop works like what you have done, `{% if the record.id == '3' %}`. But you can also generate a component function to do this as well. After creating a component for your plugin, which I suggest instead of using the builder records component.

In my Component.php I have this function.

```
public function getRecord($id) {
    $record = Model::where('id', $id)->first();
    return $record;
}
```

In my Twig Markup page I have: Note the use of **SELF** is to specify the component. If you were to expand this in a CMS page you would get `{{ componentAlias.getRecord(3) }}`.

```
{{ __SELF__.getRecord(3).image }}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Pettis! that explains it very well. 'Weird' was a bad choice of words. The component part is what my understanding was really missing. OctoberCMS, unlike other frameworks, seems to delegate some of the controllers job to a component then? Don't have enough reps to upvote answers yet but your help is truly appreciated :)

Comment: I actually understand why you wrote 'weird' I was just suggesting a change of perspective. Also yeah check out the [docs on components](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components) to understand how to build them.